# Can't install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

When I install SQL Server Express 2014,

it said that I have to install the Visual studio 2010 Service pack 1.

However, it fail in installing process. 
And here is the log record.

```
OS Version = 6.1.7601, Platform 2, Service Pack 1
OS Description = Windows 7 - x64 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 1
CommandLine = c:\91c3cc4305c28fd9a4ee\Setup.exe 
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1
Package Version = 10.0.40219
User Experience Data Collection Policy: UserControlled
Number of applicable items: 14
Summary Information:

SetupUtility
Service Pack 1 
WCF RIA service V1.0 SP1
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - CHT
Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - CHT
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - CHT
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools
Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition
Microsoft F# Redistributable Package 2.0
VSTO 4.0  Runtime x64
Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools
Microsoft Visual C++ Compilers 2010 Standard x86 - 10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual C++ Compilers 2010 Standard x64 - 10.0.40219

Cannot get the size of : c:\91c3cc4305c28fd9a4ee\$shtdwn$.req
Cannot get the size of : c:\91c3cc4305c28fd9a4ee\$shtdwn$.req
Exe (c:\91c3cc4305c28fd9a4ee\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
MSI (C:\Users\Coda\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219\VS10sp1_x86.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_20150414_222827416-MSI_VS10sp1_x86.msi.txt
MSI (C:\Users\Coda\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219\RiaServices.msi) Installation failed. Msi Log: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_20150414_222827416-MSI_RiaServices.msi.txt
MSI (C:\Users\Coda\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219\VS10sp1_x86.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_20150414_222827416-MSI_VS10sp1_x86.msi.txt
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:02:26).
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with RiaServices.msi installation.

You can fix it with this link: [WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP1 for Silverlight 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=14880) The sp1 package looks for the ria services sp1 which is the 1.1 version and not the 1.0 that you can download from here: [WCF RIA Services V1.0 for Silverlight 4 and Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3053).
You need the first file to fix your issue - install it. then when asked during sp1 installation point to the second MSI file.

I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: I try this for a while, but it still not work. So, I remove the whole system and reinstall vs,sp1 and then install sql server, and it work.

Comment: Definitely this was the second option I would offer but again this seem to me as overkill, but if it works for you that great :)